# product specs and be able to compare between products on the specs

Tags: shopify

I run table tennis products website.

I need to add product specification and way for users be able to compare between products on their specs.

Example the following product page : [product example](http://butterflyindonesia.com/collections/frontpage/products/tamca-5000-sardius)

Every blade like above will have its speed and control quality number.

So need to put this on above product page like :
Speed : 89
Quality: 70

And users can compare specs with other products side by side.

I understand I can just input the above spec on product description, but then it does not have compare system,
users will have to manualy open two screens, and thats difficult for mobile users.

Is there any in-build solution in shopify or any app that can do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it but it is not a straight forward way.

1. Create all additional fields using metafields property of the products. More information - https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/metafield
2. Create a comparison "page" where you can provide 2/3/4 drop lists for products to be used for comparison
3. Create a template for products that displays the comparison data in JSON notation. More information - https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/store/create-alternate-templates
4. As soon as a product is selected in "2", do an AJAX call to the product template in "3". You'll get the required data. Now you can arrange it in any format as you need.